# Wrong range of values in Time-series forecasting TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regression, forecasting

I have a dataset of prices with 36619 samples and 6 features. The distributions of the features vary significantly, so I create the following function to adapt a normalization layer and create a TensorFlow (TF) dataset. The description of each step is on the function as well as the parameters.`tensorflow.__version__`=2.8.2

```
WINDOW_JUMP = 24
WINDOW_SIZE = 24*7
SHIFT = 1
TARGET = 1
BATCH_SIZE = 128
SHUFFLE_BUFFER = 10000
SERIES_SHAPE = [WINDOW_SIZE,6]
```

WINDOW_SIZE results in the dataset having samples of shape 168 x 6 and the targets will be 24 (
WINDOW_JUMP) time-steps ahead.

```
def windowed_dataset(series,
    window_size, 
    window_jump, 
    target, 
    batch_size,
    shuffle_buffer,
    dim_target = 0,
    shift=1,
    processing = None):
    """Generates dataset windows

    Args:
      series (array of float) - contains the values of the time series
      window_size (int) - the number of time steps to include in the feature
      window_jump (int) - number of time steps ahead to predict
      target (int) - number of targets to predict from window_size to window_jump
      batch_size (int)
      shuffle_buffer(int) - buffer size to use for the shuffle method
      dim_target (int) - Case of a multivariate dataset, the number of the column from which to extract the targets
      shift (int) - jump between windows
      Processing (Keras.layers.preprocessing Object) - If passed, Preprocessing layer to adapt

    Returns:
      dataset (TF Dataset) - TF Dataset containing time windows and targets
    """
    print('--> Generate a TF Dataset from the series values')
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)

    if processing != None:
      print('\t --> Adapting the preprocessed layer to the data')
      processed = dataset.window(window_size, shift=shift, drop_remainder=True)
      processed = processed.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_size))
      processing.adapt(processed)

    print('--> Window the data but only take those with the specified size')
    dataset = dataset.window(window_size + window_jump, shift=shift, drop_remainder=True)
    
    print('--> Flatten the windows by putting its elements in a single batch')
    dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_size + window_jump))
    
    print('--> Create tuples with features and labels')
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:-window_jump], window[-target:][:,dim_target]))
    
    print('--> Shuffle the windows')
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer)
    
    print('--> Create batches of windows')
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
    
    if processing != None:
      print('Returning dataset and adapted layer')
      return dataset,processing
    else:
      print('Returning dataset')
      return dataset
```

The dataset was split into Train (90%), Validation (5%), and Test (5%) sets. I obtained the Train and Validation set to fit the model with the function above. In this step, I verified the values of the targets contained in each set and are in the desired range of values.

```
# Train set
train_series, normalizer_layer = windowed_dataset(train_set,
                                WINDOW_SIZE,WINDOW_JUMP,TARGET,BATCH_SIZE,SHUFFLE_BUFFER,
                                processing= tf.keras.layers.Normalization(input_shape=SERIES_SHAPE))
```

Finally, I created, compiled, and fitted the model.

```
# Train the model
def compile_fit_model(model,epochs,train_series,validation_series,lr_schedule):
  # Initialize the optimizer
  print('\nCreating optimizer with scheduler')
  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr_schedule)

  # Set the training parameters
  model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae'])

  print('\nFitting the model')
  history = model.fit(train_series, epochs=epochs)#,validation_data=validation_series)

  return history

def get_uncompile_model(input_shape,norm=None):
    '''Model with the changes proposed by Pranav Raikote'''
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    if norm != None:
        model.add(norm)
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3,
                      strides=1,
                      activation="relu",
                      padding='causal',))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64,input_shape=input_shape,return_sequences=True)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x*norm.mean))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='linear'))
    model.summary()
    return model

model = get_uncompile_model(SERIES_SHAPE,normalizer_layer)
history = compile_fit_model(model,3,train_series,val_series,1e-8)
```

I am getting the following prediction from the validation data, I don't expect it to be accurate, after all, I haven't tuned It. However, It should at least be able to get into the range of correct values, right? I have tried the linear activation function in the last layer and various configurations for the Neural Network but nothing worked. I have followed the TF tutorial on Regression for beginners but I can't find anything wrong.

[image]

Can someone please help me to identify what I am doing wrong?. I am relatively new to Time-Series and TensorFlow. If you find any annotations to add different from the question, feel free to tell me, I will be grateful.

**Note**

This is the prediction of the validation set with the new model, It has more Dense and Dropout layers before the output(Ten Epochs). Before I used the same model excluding the Dropout, Dense(6), and Lambda layers, the results were slightly different from the first image.
[image]

Comment: Only 1 neutron in SimpleRNN() isn't enough. Add a proper LSTM layer with at least 32 neurons and train it for a few epochs (~10). Results will be much better. Also linear activation is the correct activation at output layer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pranav, I tried something like that before and as you said indeed improves the shape but the value range keeps far below the desired one. I have seen some examples where the last layer is a lambda to scale the output and "help" the model, but I wasn't quite convinced.

Comment: I haven't come across examples using Lambda layer, but since the activation is linear, that should result in properly scaled real number outputs. Also, remove the preprocessing you are using from keras and then check. In a few cases, we might not need pre-processing. One more thing to try is some dropout and a Dense layer before the output layer.

Comment: That helps a lot, the extra Dense and Dropout layers before the output layer enhanced the learning process. However, for the record, the lambda layer also helps, with ten Epochs, It takes for the model one epoch to achieve the same as the one without a Lambda layer. I don't know if this approach would be better in the long run, after all, It is a fixed value. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: That's great, happy to help. Also, I'm interested in the Lambda layer aspect. Can you send me the resource surrounding it?

Comment: I found it [here](https://github.com/https-deeplearning-ai/tensorflow-1-public/blob/main/C4/W3/ungraded_labs/C4_W3_Lab_1_RNN.ipynb). It is a Git-Hub repository of time-series and TF course. They only recommend it as help but don't go into the specifics.